# AJAX to asmx (VB) webmethod - GET with parameters

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web-services, asmx

I've been reading a lot of questions about this error, but just can't seem to get around it (it's incredible how many questions can be found on the web on this topic!!). Let me be straight:

#### test.asmx

```
'Simple POST (obviously with parameters)
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
<ScriptMethodAttribute(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Function TestarPost(ByVal Valor as String) As String
  Dim x
End Function

'Simple GET - no parameters
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
<ScriptMethodAttribute(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)>
Public Function Testar() As String
        return "ok ;>D"
End Function

'GET with parameters
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
<ScriptMethodAttribute(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)>
Public Function TestarGet(ByVal Valor as String) As String
        return Valor
End Function
```

Trying it out in js console window:

```
  obj = { Valor: "x" }
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.asmx/TestarPost",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify(obj),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(ret) {
          console.log(ret.d);
      },
      error: function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {
          console.log(xhr.status + "||" + xhr.responseText);
      }
  });
```

> **Success!**

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ServerSide.asmx/Testar",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(ret) {
          console.log(ret.d);
      },
      error: function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {
          console.log(xhr.status + "||" + xhr.responseText);
      }
  });
```

> **Success!** Returns correctly data in JSON format

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "test.asmx/TestarGet",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify(obj),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(ret) {
          console.log(ret.d);
      },
      error: function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {
          console.log(xhr.status + "||" + xhr.responseText);
      }
  });
```

> **Fails!** Doing the same as in Post

The message error is "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027Valor\u0027." Also fails if I send object literal ("Invalide JSON primitive"). However, if I access URL .../ServerSide.asmx/TestarGet?Valor=x, it returns "opa" (maybe a clue?)

What I don't get (pardon the pun) is why, since it's the same as in POST. Maybe because the POST isn't affecting anything and I can't see the result (but it returns no errors, at least).

My goal is to create a function *serverSide(asmxMethod, obj)* to make a generalized bridge between client and server functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution (but not an answer). According to a friend, GET doesn't accept json parameters. Unfortunately, even if I send dataType: "text" it fails.

The solution is to use always POST. POST is also able to return data (didn't know that). So with the POST example I can send and receive data in json format without a problem.